# Terraform Digitalocean: move resources under project

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean

I want to create N droplets on DigitalOcean and assign them to a DigitalOcean project (that is not yet existing).

First I'm creating a project and I assign the droplets to the project using the `resources` item. I'm also creating the two droplets.

```
resource "digitalocean_project" "project" {
  name        = "playground"
  count       = "2"
  description = "Description"
  purpose     = "Description purposes"
  environment = "Development"
  resources = [
    digitalocean_droplet.myserver[count.index].urn
  ]
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "myserver" {
    count = "2"
    name = "server-${count.index}"
    image = "ubuntu-18-04-x64"
    size = "1gb"
    region = "${var.region}"
}
```

The droplets are created successfully. One droplet is moved to the newly created project, while the other droplet remains in my default project.

The error message is below is clear. It tries to create a second project with the same name.

> Error: Error creating Project: POST
>   https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/projects: 409 name is already in use
>   (duplicate)
>
> on create_server.tf line 1, in resource "digitalocean_project"
>   "project":    1: resource "digitalocean_project" "project" {

How can I assign the two droplets to my project (which I want to create dynamically)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one project with multiple resources then you need to only create a single project and assign the list of resources to it. To do this you'll want to remove the `count` parameter from the `digitalocean_project` resource (this would create multiple projects) and then use the [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions) of the `digitalocean_droplet` resources to pass a list of the resources to the project.

So you want something that looks a little like this:

```
resource "digitalocean_project" "project" {
  name        = "playground"
  description = "Description"
  purpose     = "Description purposes"
  environment = "Development"
  resources   = digitalocean_droplet.myserver[*].urn
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "myserver" {
  count  = "2"
  name   = "server-${count.index}"
  image  = "ubuntu-18-04-x64"
  size   = "1gb"
  region = var.region
}
```

Comment: I tried that but then it gives me `Inappropriate value for attribute "resources": element 0: string required.` error message

Comment: Fixed it. I had to do the following `resources = digitalocean_droplet.myserver.*.urn`. If you modify your answer I can accept it. As the idea came from you.

Comment: Derp, sorry, missed that. Fixed now.

Comment: It should be `digitalocean_droplet.myserver.*.urn`. Otherwise does not work. Can you update so I can accept the answer.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR how can add the new droplets to the existing project